# Are there any extensions to handle a 1 month free trial for a paid membership in civicrm?

Tags: civimember

Using civicrm / wordpress

I would have thought there would already be an extension or setting to have a 1 week / 1 month etc free trial when a member signs up as a paid member, but I cannot see this option.

Does anyone know of an extension to handle this or does it need custom development?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anything that does that but a lot depends how you want things to behave.

What makes this trial month different to normal membership?  Do you want them to be able to cancel and get a refund in that month? If so, that depends on how you take payments.

I'd look at adding a month to the membership end date and using the status rules so the first month has a status of 'Trial'.

Comment: Thanks. the interesting problem I have is we are looking to capture payment with stripe then only collect after initial trial period and put them on the first period of a recurring subscription

Comment: Have a 1 month non-recurring membership type of "trial".

As month ends send message with links to standard "annual" membership sign up?

Not sure how you'd stop people from just endlessly taking multiple trail memberships in that scenario though